# making a transformed element the child of a sibling

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I am doing a MODS to MODS transform on the following xml. I have greatly simplified it for clarity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OAI-PMH>
  <metadata>
    <mods>
      <genre>Negatives (photographic)</genre>
      <genre>Cellulose nitrate film</genre>
      <physicalDescription>
        <form>Photograph</form>
      </physicalDescription>
    </mods>
</metadata></OAI-PMH>
```

I need this result, where the `genre` elements have been been made `form` elements that are children of the already existing `physicalTransform` element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OAI-PMH>
  <metadata>
    <mods>
      <physicalDescription>
        <form>Photograph</form>
        <form>Negatives (photographic)</form>
        <form>Cellulose nitrate film</form>
      </physicalDescription>
    </mods>
</metadata></OAI-PMH>
```

How do I go about doing this? I have tried this:

```
<xsl:template match="mods:physicalDescription">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="mods:genre"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="mods:genre">
    <xsl:element namespace="http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3" name="form" >
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/> 
    </xsl:element>  
</xsl:template>
```

But it is not working. I am sure I am missing something simple, but I cannot determine what. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are referring to a namespace, but did not declare this namespace in your input XML. I assume it is a default namespace:

**XML Input**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OAI-PMH xmlns="http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3">
  <metadata>
    <mods>
      <genre>Negatives (photographic)</genre>
      <genre>Cellulose nitrate film</genre>
      <physicalDescription>
        <form>Photograph</form>
      </physicalDescription>
    </mods>
</metadata>
</OAI-PMH>
```

In the stylesheet you posted, there are invisible whitespace characters that you should remove. Also, there should be a mechanism that produces a faithful copy of the input, on the basis of which you can define changes - this is called an *identity template*.

Then, inside a template match for `mods:physicalDescription`, find all `mods:genre` elements that are sibling elements and output an element `form` for each of them, in the same namespace.

Add one last template that matches `mods:genre`, it is no longer necessary to process them separately.

**XSLT Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
xmlns:mods="http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3"
exclude-result-prefixes="mods">

    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="mods:physicalDescription">
        <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="../mods:genre">
            <form xmlns="http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </form>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="mods:genre"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**XML Output**

As you can see, this produces exactly the output you have requested, except the default namespace that you did not include.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OAI-PMH xmlns="http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3">
   <metadata>
      <mods>
         <physicalDescription>
            <form>Photograph</form>
            <form>Negatives (photographic)</form>
            <form>Cellulose nitrate film</form>
         </physicalDescription>
      </mods>
   </metadata>
</OAI-PMH>
```

Comment: Thank you. I perhaps oversimplified the examples. I was already using the identity template in my actual code, as well as using the correct namespaces. I probably should have removed the mods: prefix from the templates, as this was misleading. In any case, thank you for your answer, which does indeed solve the problem. I will remember to be more careful when constructing the examples.

Comment: @jmignault You are welcome. If you have a question on how to integrate this answer into your existing code, please post all of it and I'm glad to help. But in that case you should ask a new question.